# how can I stop the interval in java script for 15 seconds?

Tags: javascript

I want to break the interval in JS for some time, let's say for 15 seconds.
Currently my code looks like this:

```
var currentDate = new Date().setMilliseconds(0)+4000;
check();

function check() {

            //console.log("now "+new Date());

            var dateOfText = new Date().setMilliseconds(0);
            console.log("date1 "+currentDate);
            console.log("date2 "+dateOfText);

            if (currentDate - dateOfText ==0) {
                console.log("hey I'm in if");
                //how can I stay here for 15 seconds?
            } else{
                //console.log(new Date());
                console.log("im in else");
            }
        }

        var myInterval = setInterval(check, 1000);
```

and I want to stay in the if statement for longer than just a second - however later on I want to continue with displaying the else message.
How can I do it?
Here is myfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eo39peh6/

Comment: Simple answer, you can't. You cannot pause javascript execution, with the exception of doing something like alert/confirm dialogs. The best you could do is clear the interval and restart it after 15 seconds, but you cannot pause in the middle of the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the interval, then set a timeout of 15 seconds that reset the interval.

```js
var myInterval;

function check() {

  //console.log("now "+new Date());

  var dateOfText = new Date().setMilliseconds(0);
  console.log("date1 " + currentDate);
  console.log("date2 " + dateOfText);

  if (currentDate - dateOfText == 0) {
    console.log("hey I'm in if");
    clearInterval(myInterval); // stop interval
    setTimeout(function() { // set timeout of 15 seconds
      myInterval = setInterval(check, 1000); // reset interval
    }, 15000);

  } else {
    //console.log(new Date());
    console.log("im in else");
  }
}

myInterval = setInterval(check, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `clearInterval()`.

```
var myInterval;
var delay = 15000;
function check() {
  var dateOfText = new Date().setMilliseconds(0);
  console.log("date1 " + currentDate);
  console.log("date2 " + dateOfText);

  if (currentDate - dateOfText == 0) {
    console.log("hey I'm in if");
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    setTimeout(function() {
      myInterval = setInterval(check, 1000);
    }, delay);

  } else {
    //console.log(new Date());
    console.log("im in else");
  }
}

myInterval = setInterval(check, 1000);
```